# Is there a way to create an R knitr program file which is also an R (console) program file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I've started using knitr (without pander) and I'm very impressed.

I can find instructions for writing inline knitr markdown – which will be processed even though a hash is written at the beginning of a line (which will be useful). However, it has occurred to me that if knitr can read and process such information, perhaps there is a way to write ALL markdown instructions e.g. ```` ```{r} ```` with a hash at the beginning of the line ? I.e., I would like it if ```` ##```{r} ```` also worked when run via knit.

This would allow me to create files which work without errors when run using R console and also when run via knit – which might be useful when files are submitted for review.

Comment: You could keep your R code in an annotated R file and include the chunks in your RMarkdown document as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/read-chunk.html). Alternatively, you could write a regular RMarkdown document and extract the code via [purl()](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/purl.html) when you need plain code for a submission.

Comment: Many thanks CL !! - It appears that the read_chunk commands may do the trick. Apparently I can simply write ## ---- test-a -------- at the top of a 70 page script, create a 5 line .Rmd file which contains ```{r, include=TRUE, cache=FALSE} and knitr::read_chunk('test.R') and ```{r, test-a, echo=TRUE} and then a short master file to knit the .Rmd file - and the whole 70 pages will be knitted without any pesky non-R markdown coding !! very nice (although I'm still at the testing stage). Can I upvote this answer ?

Comment: Well almost - knit managed around 3 pages then it decided I didn't want the rest of the code for some reason ! I've started to use RStudio just in case this has better memory handling than the console - and into the script I'm putting a ## ---- label -------- every so often and expanding the Rmd file every time with {r, label, echo=TRUE} - so far so good.

Comment: You say that knitr ignores code after a certain point. Is there anything special at this point? Any comments, maybe?

Comment: By the way, you might also be interested in [`knitr::spin()`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/spin.html).

Comment: Conclusion - at most 16 labels to keep knit awake for 30 pages of coding ! No idea why knit suddenly thinks the rest is text not code - but maybe to do with lots of text in R comments (?) (after two hashes): ## long comment. ## more long comments, some more coding. (As far as I know spin needs a hash at the beginning of a coding line (?) - or am I mistaken ?), The important thing is that I now have an intact R script which can be run in R console without throwing errors - but with mark-up commands which, via .Rmd and master files can give the knit.